# Ionic: $state.go() changes URL but not the view

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm totally new to Ionic and JavaScript and I'm having a few problems when changing views in my project.

I've created the project using the tabs starter, and everything works when moving withing the default tabs and even when adding new ones. At certain parts of the code, I need to move to a tab view so I'm using the `$state.go()` function and it works fine. However, I've added a new view with its template, controller, and state and I need to load it when clicking a button. So I use `$state.go()` again, but the URL in the explorer changes but not the view, it stays in the previous one. It doesn't work either when I type the URL in the browser, so maybe the problem is in the state definition, but I'm pretty sure it is ok.

**State**

```
.state('tab.file_explorer', {
    url: '/file_explorer',
    views: {
      'tab-file_explorer': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-file_explorer.html',
        controller: 'file_explorerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**Controller**
It is in the controller of another view where the button is located (the button works fine, I've tested it). The `file_explorerCtrl` controller is empty at the moment.

```
.controller('load_csvCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.loadCsv = function(){
       $state.go('tab.file_explorer');
    }
}
```

This redirects to the URL http://localhost:8100/#/tab/file_explorer, with no console output or 404 errors. I've also tried using `$location.path()` and `$window.location.assign()` but it also fails to load the template.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: add a console.log('inside loadcsv') inside  $scope.loadCsv to check if its fired. to that with other part of code when you think it might fail then you can track it.

Comment: @Flakerim yes, $scope.loadCsv is fired.

Comment: @RalkaiShagtten Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your index.html has `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` tag

Comment: Yes, it does, at the end of the <body> section.

Answer (score 0):

You're using named views. your `<ion-nav-view>` should match the name:

`<ion-nav-view name="tab-file_explorer"></ion-nav-view>`

Check the docs here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Nothing, I've tried it but it's the same. The URL changes but the view remais the same.

Comment: you should paste the html

Answer (score 0):

Set `cache-view="false"` in View.

Example:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
<!-- View Content goes here -->
</ion-view>
```